# How long does it take different operations with Threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I program Java and I want to make my multithread programs work faster.

I know that setting/reading boolean variable is faster than locking/unlocking of mutex.
Locking/unlocking is faster than making thread sleep or wake.
And sleep/wake pair is faster than creating absolutely new thread.

I know that this processes are specific for different hardware and OS. But is there any estimations of lead time?
I look for something like "10 times to sleep/wake lasts as long as 1 time to create new thread".

Comment: The dependence on specific hardware and OS may be too much to even give an estimate. Why don't you code a simple benchmark for _your_ system and run it? But first think, aren't you entering the dreaded Premature Optimization Land?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make my multithread programs work faster

The best way to focus on this is to Memory and CPU profile your application.  I suggest memory profiling first as this often has the quickest wins.  As you didn't mention it, perhaps you hadn't though about it but you can be losing 50+% of your performance to creating and cleaning up objects if you are not careful.

After you have cleaned up your memory consumption, you can do a CPU profiling.  This is useful but sometimes harder to see how you can improve it without restructuring your application.  There is a good chance this is what you need to do to reduce consumption.  A common question for me is;  do I know that adding more threads really helps.  If I don't know this because I measure it, it could equally be hurting.  You might be amazed how much you can speed up a multi-threaded application, in particular it's worse case latencies, by taking out threads.

Finally if you want to go to a lower level, try Flight Recorder in Java Mission Control.  This is a lower level view.  Some think this is better than a profiler, but these people tend to write efficient code in the first place.  I think most developers should start with a profiler.

> I know that this processes are specific for different hardware and OS. But is there any estimations of lead time?

They also vary by how much you use them and in a multi-threaded context, how much does one operation slow down another thread. i.e. if you obtain a lock which is;

- only ever used by one thread it is pretty cheap.
- rarely shared by another thread it costs significantly more
- is actually being held by another thread it can take much longer.

How much time a lock takes depends on how it is used.

Another problem is a questions of what is the bottle neck.  If you bottle neck is CPU consumption using more threads can help to spread the load but if the problem is CPU to memory bandwidth of L3 cache consumption, more threads can be slower.

In short, too much depends on what you are doing, find the bottleneck and reduce it, then find the next bottleneck etc.